# Web Videos via Watch Folders Transcode

Tags: mac, transcoding, webvideos

What I am looking to do is fairly simple, however seems complicated in theory.

What I need to do is be able to have a folder where all video files placed in the folder, are transcoded to all applicable web video formats (H264, OGG, WEBM, FLV) Then placed into another folder...

I can set this up to a certain extent using Adobe Media Encoder however I need to use source Frame Rate, and Frame Size, as these clips will vary in range from PAL to NTSC to HD...

I am open to using FFmpeg but cant seem to get it work in the Mac Environment correctly doing what I want.  Any software as long as it is mac based would work, but must be able to create all 4 of the above mentioned formats.

Comment: If you want to use ffmpeg a bash script would help you a lot to automate the process. [Here's](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2017284) an example of a similar bash script using ffmpeg to batch convert video's in iTunes friendly format. If you're a bit code-savvy you could rewrite it to webm, ogg, h264 and flv. [Here's](http://paulrouget.com/e/converttohtml5video/) a little bit of text on the latter conversion using ffmpeg.

Comment: This is what I am working on now, I am in the process of getting ffmpeg to work correctly and then go from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...FFMPEG worked, it was a steep learning curve in terms of getting it to work in my environment and, took me a few days to learn how to code in Bash Scripts Shell based, but in the end very happy with the results and it's integration with both Macs and my Unix server.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a droplet in compressor.  Unfortunately, your options for destination folder are limited by this method to either source, desktop, cluster storage, or your movie folder.  Since you don't want your watch folder endlessly copying movies, "source" is a bad choice, and you probably don't have cluster storage, so as long as you're ok with your destination being movies or desktop, you could use automator to make a watch folder that performs the Finder->open action using your droplet as the application.

I'm sure someone will chime in here with a better solution soon.

*edit*  You can change a droplet's destination to any folder you want.  Just open it in the finder after you've created it and change the destination.

Comment: I will look into this, I absolutely hate compressor however if it does the job correctly and efficiently I may need to use it...however I do not believe (may be possible just havnt looked into it) that compressor does not support theora (ogg or webm) or flv

Comment: I am unable to successfully convert to OGG using several different codec variations, so compressor will not work, I also have yet to find a solution for converting to webM and FLV